# RCurl equivalent of -H and --data-binary in curl

Tags: r, post, curl, rcurl

How do I translate this POST request that was sent using `curl`, into the equivalent RCurl command?

`curl 'http://www.example.com/example' -H 'Origin: http://www.example.com' -H 'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8' --data-binary '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> <soap:Header><clsSoapHeader xmlns="http://www.example.com/example"></clsSoapHeader></soap:Header><soap:Body><example-tag></example-tag></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>'`

Comment: RCurl uses libcurl, not the command-line, so the relevant [reference documentation is here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html). You can basically directly use any of the `curl_easy_setopt` options directly in a call to `curlPerform`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on suggestion by @Thomas, here's the solution I've found

```
        h <- basicTextGatherer()
        url <- 'http://www.example.com/example'
        body <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> <soap:Header><clsSoapHeader xmlns="http://www.example.com/example"></clsSoapHeader></soap:Header><soap:Body><example-tag></example-tag></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>'
        curlPerform(url = url, httpheader=c(Accept="text/xml", Accept="multipart/*", 'Content-Type' = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"), postfields=body, writefunction = h$update, verbose = TRUE)
```

Then, the result can be accessed via `h$update()`